# Lexicographic compare of two strings in Velocity

Tags: string, velocity, lexicographic-ordering

I have two string variables in a Velocity template. I want to do a lexicographic compare. I tried this:

```
#if ($string1 > $string2)
  #set ($largest = $string1)
#else
  #set ($largest = $string2)
#end
## (assume `$string1` and `$string2` are never Null)
```

So, if `$string1` contains the string `"dog"` and `$string2` contains the string `"cat"`, then `$largest` will end up containing the string `"dog"`.

The above code generates this message:

```
Left side of '>=' operation is not a Number
```

How can I do the compare I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java String's [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) method to compare strings

> The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string

```
#if ($string1.compareTo($string2) > 0)
  #set ($largest = $string1)
#else
  #set ($largest = $string2)
#end
```